# Combo with 2D borders on XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I am working with XAML. How can I add a combo box with flat borders (Not 3D)?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a new template for the `ComboBox`. There is a package of basic templates called *Simple Styles,* which you can read about [here](http://learnwpf.com/Posts/Post.aspx?postId=be7aea6e-82c2-4354-a6e0-b0118d951999), that includes the essential display and functionality with none of the fancy effects. The styles are also included with [Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/), and the combo-box style provides the simple 2D look you are probably going for.